# Getting Empty Dictionary and output into newline

Tags: python-3.x

Why i'm returinig with a empty dictionary at the end `{}` and dictionary output into newline ..

```
import re
with open("Namefile1", "r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        #line = line.strip()
        ageC = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}', line)
        nameC = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*', line)
        ageDict = {}
        x = 0
        for eachname in nameC:
            ageDict[eachname] = ageC[x]
            x+=1
        print(ageDict)
```

Result:

```
$ ./nameExcercise1.py
{'Alia': '30', 'Celina': '30'}
{'Soma': '40', 'Beena': '40'}
{}
```

While it should be:

```
 {'Alia': '30', 'Celina': '30', 'Soma': '40', 'Beena': '40'}
```

File:

```
$ cat Namefile1
Alia is 30 and Celina is 28
Soma is 40 and Beena is 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the "third" line of the file is empty, so contains no ages or names.

And if you want to combine the results of all lines into a single dictionary, don't re-initialize it for each line.

Comment: How to get that without re-initialize ?

Comment: Initialize it before the loop, not in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip empty lines:

```
if not line.strip(): continue
```

An empty line (consisting of nothing more than a newline character and perhaps some other whitespace such as spaces or tabs) doesn't contain any names and ages, nor is easy to spot when it's the last line in your file and you are using `cat` to output the file to a terminal.